# Are dockerized C++ applications backwards compatible to earlier kernel versions?

Tags: c++, linux, docker

Say I have a C++ application running in a docker container using modern linux distribution (Ubuntu 19.10) with the related versions of GCC and linux kernel. The container itself is hosted on Ubuntu 19.10.

I build my application in the container and statically link all of my dependencies except those that are provided by the system, namely libc++, libc, etc. These come from those bundled in the underlying Docker image. As far as my application knows, it lives in Ubuntu 19.10.

I then proceed to deploy the Docker image containing my application binary on a much older Linux kernel (say whatever CentOS 6 is using).

Is there a risk of incompatibility (ABI or otherwise) doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a risk. You need to check `libc` requirements to see what kernel version it supported. Usually `libc` is the gateway to the kernel for most softwares except for some languages that it implemented it own system calls.